# Attaching method to function prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to attach a method `mytest` to a function prototype:

```js
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    var a = (e) => document.querySelector(e);

    a.prototype.mytest = function(e){ ... };
        
    //example div
    a("div").mytest("d");
  }();
})();
```

But I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mytest' of undefined"

Comment: `a` doesn't have a prototype because it uses an arrow function. Try swapping it for a "regular" function? `a = function () { ...`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Please clear the question. You'll get voted down if you post ambiguous question here.

Comment: similar to jquery $("#div").example("test")

but it is not jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you fix the fact that the arrow function has no prototype by using a regular function, you cant assign to the prototype of the value *returned* by that function. So you'll never be able to call `a(...).mytest(...)`.

Maybe this is along the lines of what you were trying to achieve

```js
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {

    const a = (e) => ({
        elem: document.querySelector(e),
        mytest: function(e) { console.log(this.elem, e) }
      })


    //example div
    a("div").mytest("d");

  }();
})();
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `a` has no prototype since it is run it with inline ES6 arrow syntax.

Try

```
function a(e) {
    return document.querySelector(e);
}
```

And then the rest of your code should work, granted you have any "div" elements in your code

Although if you can just set a prototype function like that, might as well clean it up and make your "a" into a class so you can set different properties

Comment: I will fix that

Comment: Just changing the arrow func to a regular function doesnt fix the wider issue that assigning `mytest` to the prototype of the function does not let you call it on  the _result_ of the function.